# What are the benefits of participating in workshops related to good conferences?

Tags: publications, conference, workshop

I just received the acceptance notification of my paper in one of the workshops related to ECML/PKDD conference which is among good conferences in computer science.

However, my paper is accepted as a poster and its chances of being selected for the printed proceeding may be low, which means it could be useless for my CV. But I have to pay 400 euros for the registration plus travel costs. Although I use my travel grant, I do not like to just waste the budget.

So I was wondering how worthwhile is for me to present my work there.

Comment: What does your supervisor say?

Comment: @astronat he is generally fine with workshops, and doesn't have my concerns. He says it's up to me!

Comment: Related: [What is the point in publishing a paper in a workshop rather than in a conference?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/86220/what-is-the-point-in-publishing-a-paper-in-a-workshop-rather-than-in-a-conferenc/86225#86225)

Comment: What typically happens in workshops in your field. In some fields they can be very valuable. I don't know about all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a certain point in your career it might be very valuable to attend. In some CS fields workshops are a great place to extend your learning. They are also a great place to make professional contacts that will serve you well as you grow into the profession. I don't work in Machine Learning, however, and can't speak specifically for workshops at this conference.

In some conference, "workshop" actually means getting help in improving your work or at least getting feedback on it from a wider audience than you normally have. This, again, is valuable for a new scholar.

If you haven't attended a lot of good conferences, attendance itself for a student can be very valuable for the same reasons stated above. Senior faculty will often wander around in the poster area just to meet people, encourage them and look for potential future junior faculty.

Like anything, you may need to balance the funds against other opportunities, but it could, depending on circumstances, be well spent here. If you haven't been to the conference in the past, your advisor or other faculty can give you an idea about what goes on.